# Multiple modals and attaching different events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one modal with error handling that I open from jquery. The modal has button with some class, to which I connect the event.

The problem is that each time I open the modal, the event is attached to the same class. How do I deal with this?

Comment: Can we see your code to better understand how you did it?  I have a feeling that each time you call the function it appends the handler to the event, but doesnt recreate the modal in general.  Would like to see code in order to confirm and give a proper answer

Comment: where's the code ? pls attach a fiddle or something